# Prove inequality for every positive integer

Tags: inequality

> Prove that for every positive integer $n$ :
>   $ \frac {1}{3}+ \frac{2}{3\cdot5}+\ldots+ \frac{n}{3\cdot5\cdot \ldots \cdot(2n+1)}<\frac{1}{2}$.

I see sum is $\frac {1}{2}-\frac{1}{2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot \ldots \cdot(2n+1)}$ and it's easy now with induction but I'm looking for other solutions.

Comment: If the sum you found is correct then isn't it fairly obvious that the second expression is always positive, hence the sum is less than 1/2 or are you looking for something else?

Comment: where have you found this inequality?

Comment: I found this inequality in pdf from school math club. If sum I found is correct i have to prove it by induction by I think about proof without induction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using the identity $n!=\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^n e^{-x}\,dx$ and the change of variable $x=y^2/2$ we have:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{n}{(2n+1)!!}&=&\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{n 2^n n!}{(2n+1)!}<\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{n (2x)^n}{(2n+1)!}e^{-x}\,dx\\&=&\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(y\cosh y-\sinh y\right) e^{-y^2/2}\,dy=\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}},\end{eqnarray*}$$
since a primitive of the last integrand function is just $-e^{-y^2/2}\cosh y.$